# LNK 2019  При вызове объекта шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, visual-studio, шаблоны-с++

Ошибка происходит при инициализации объекта класса Interface;

```
Interface <int> test;
```

Если убрать шаблон из класса, то ошибка пропадает.

Interface.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Interface
{
private:
    T dummy;
public:
    Interface();
    ~Interface();
//  void menu(void);
};
```

Interface.cpp:

```
#include "Interface.h"

template <class T>
Interface<T>::Interface()
{
}

template <class T>
Interface<T>::~Interface()
{

}
```

Список ошибок:

```
Ошибка  1   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall Interface<int>::Interface<int>(void)" (??0?$Interface@H@@QAE@XZ) в функции _main
Ошибка  2   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall Interface<int>::~Interface<int>(void)" (??1?$Interface@H@@QAE@XZ) в функции _main 
Ошибка  3   error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена переносом кода из .cpp в .h файл. Тем не менее, есть ли способы описать шаблонный класс раздельно?

Comment: @zesam: Нету, никак не возможно в C++.

Читайте: [[1]](/questions/270465/#270534), [[2]](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/separate-template-class-defn-from-decl.html).